# Angular rxjs request parallel and sequencial

Tags: rxjs, angular5

I need to execute parallel requests and after all those requests are done, I need to execute one more call.

```
public loadAppData() {
  // get current Data
  let currentData: any = this.sourceAppData.getValue();

  // load userInfo
  return this.storage.get('userInfo').then((userInfo) => {
    this.userInfo = userInfo;

    // call endpoints
    let products = this.loadProducts();
    let customers = this.loadCustomers();
    let priceRules = this.loadPriceRules();
    let shop = this.loadShop();

    // load in parallel
    return forkJoin([products, customers, priceRules, shop]).subscribe(results => {
      let currentData: any = this.sourceAppData.getValue();
      currentData.products = results[0];
      currentData.customers = results[1];
      currentData.priceRules = results[2];
      currentData.shop = results[3][0];
      this.updateAppData(currentData);
    });
    // I need one more request here
  });
}
```

After the ForkJoin I need to make one more call, because I have an information in one of those calls that I rely on. The problem is that I have already subscribed to the call.

How can I execute a forkJoin, get the results of the fork join, do one more request and than it should do the regular flow (like subscribe to it).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `mergeMap` after the `forkJoin` call. And could use `mergeMap`'s result selector to add one more result to the array of results:

```ts
return forkJoin([products, customers, priceRules, shop]).pipe(
  mergeMap(
    results => oneMoreOperation(results),
    (results, oneMoreResult) => [...results, oneMoreResult]
  )
).subscribe(resultsWithOneMoreResult => {
  ...
});
```

Where `oneMoreOperation` is a function that returns an [`ObservbleInput`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/Observable.ts#L20).